# enclose substring into span using string.replace javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I have this code

```js
var rxp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))", "gm");
var str = '<div id="rep"> asd 123 asd <span class="new">123</span> asd 123 asd <span class="light">123</span> </div>';
str.replace(rxp, "<span class='highlight' ondragover='event.preventDefault()' ondrop='drop(event)'>$1</span>");
```

Problem is I want to enclose `123` in `span` tag with class `highlight` but it also enclose `<span class="new">123</span>` and `<span class="light">123</span>` into another `span` tag with class `highlight` for example first one enclosed like this `<span class="new"><span class="highlight">123</span></span>` while I want it same as it was before the function of `replace`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8ntf6t8y/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a negative look-ahead after your pattern to make sure we are not enclosing another span tag.

```js
var rxp = new RegExp("([0-9]+(\\.?[0-9]+)?)(?![^<]*</span>)", "gm");
var str = '<div id="rep"> asd 123 asd <span class="new">123</span> asd 123 asd <span class="light">123</span> </div>';
document.getElementById("res").value = str.replace(rxp, "<span class='highlight' ondragover='event.preventDefault()' ondrop='drop(event)'>$1</span>");
```

```html
<input id="res"/>
```

Output:

```
NEW: <div id="rep"> asd <span class='highlight' ondragover='event.preventDefault()' ondrop='drop(event)'>123</span> asd <span class="new">123</span> asd <span class='highlight' ondragover='event.preventDefault()' ondrop='drop(event)'>123</span> asd <span class="light">123</span> </div>

OLD: <div id="rep"> asd                                                                                  123        asd <span class="new">123</span> asd                                                                                  123        asd <span class="light">123</span> </div>
```